# Render Problem : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Tags: android, android-studio-electric-eel

[Problem occurs after updating my dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRRns.png)

[These are the libraries I have added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZgsI.png)

> This is my xml file.

Please solve this problem as I have tried it many times

> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
> at android.view.BridgeInflater.lambda$createViewFromCustomInflater$0(BridgeInflater.java:259)
> at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromCustomInflater(BridgeInflater.java:285)
> at android.view.BridgeInflater.onCreateView(BridgeInflater.java:122)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:934)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:954)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1008)
> at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:309)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:965)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1127)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1101)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:686)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:505)
> at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:360)
> at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:443)
> at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:121)
> at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:722)
> at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$9(RenderTask.java:879)
> at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderExecutor$runAsyncActionWithTimeout$3.run(RenderExecutor.kt:194)
> at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderExecutor$PriorityRunnable.run(RenderExecutor.kt:292)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
> at android.graphics.fonts.Font_Builder_Delegate.createBuffer(Font_Builder_Delegate.java:52)
> at android.graphics.fonts.Font$Builder.createBuffer(Font.java:264)
> at android.graphics.fonts.Font$Builder.(Font.java:200)
> at android.graphics.Typeface$Builder.(Typeface.java:517)
> at android.graphics.Typeface_Delegate.createFromDisk(Typeface_Delegate.java:91)
> at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.ResourceHelper.getFont(ResourceHelper.java:495)
> at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.ResourceHelper.getFont(ResourceHelper.java:507)
> at android.content.res.BridgeTypedArray.getFont(BridgeTypedArray.java:723)
> at android.widget.TextView.readTextAppearance(TextView.java:4154)
> at android.widget.TextView.(TextView.java:1165)
> at android.widget.TextView.(TextView.java:1066)
> at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.(AppCompatTextView.java:113)
> at com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView.(MaterialTextView.java:88)
> at com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView.(MaterialTextView.java:83)
> at com.google.android.material.theme.MaterialComponentsViewInflater.createTextView(MaterialComponentsViewInflater.java:61)
> at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:148)
> ... 28 more

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    tools:context=".LoginActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:text="@string/chatter_box"
        android:textColor="#009688"
        android:textSize="28sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"

        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:fontFamily=""
        android:text="@string/verify_your_number"
        android:textColor="@color/teal_200"
        android:textSize="28sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should specify a fontFamily on the `TextView` otherwise you'll get a crash on the preview.

For instance, let's say that you want to use Sans-Serif then the code will look like this:

```
    <TextView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
       android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
       android:text="@string/app_name"
       android:textColor="@color/teal_200"
       android:textSize="28sp"
       android:textStyle="bold"/>
```